# Populate Field in Grid with selection of another Field

Tags: gridview, customization, acumatica

This specifically pertains to the Service Management module of Acumatica. On the Service Orders screen (SD300100) and under the Labor Tab. We would like when a new row is created and a Model Number is selected then the Service ID would automatically be populated based on what model number that is selected.

I have coded this:

```
protected void FSSODetService_ServiceID_FieldSelecting(PXCache cache, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
    {

        var service = (FSSODetService)e.Row;
        if (service == null) return;
        var equipment = (FSEquipment)PXSelect<FSEquipment,
        Where<FSEquipment.SMEquipmentID, Equal<Required<FSSODetService.SMEquipmentID>>>>.Select(Base, service.ServiceID);
        if (equipment != null)
        {
            e.ReturnValue = equipment.EquipmentTypeID;
        }
    }
```

This is leaving me this error when published.

```
\App_RuntimeCode\ServiceOrderEntry.cs(54): error CS0118: 'FieldService.ServiceDispatch.FSEquipment.SMEquipmentID' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'
\App_RuntimeCode\ServiceOrderEntry.cs(54): error CS0118: 'FieldService.ServiceDispatch.FSSODet.SMEquipmentID' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'
```

I feel like it has something to do with the setup of the Database values as they are capital in the beginning instead of lowercase. If any one has some knowledge about this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field name that start with a capital letter reference the property value field.
Field name that start with a lower letter reference the type of the field.

In BQL query, you don't provide the values of the field to the query. You provide the type of the field so you have to use lowercase first letter:

```
PXSelect<FSEquipment,
Where<FSEquipment.sMEquipmentID, Equal<Required<FSSODetService.sMEquipmentID>>>>
```

In BQL query parameters you use the property value instead of the type so you use capital letter:

```
.Select(Base, service.ServiceID)
```

**EDIT:**
You found a bug in the naming convention for the FieldService product. 
Instead of making the first letter upper/lower case like that: 'sMEquipmentID' / 'SMEquipmentID'

```
public abstract class sMEquipmentID : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
public virtual int? SMEquipmentID { get; set; }
```

They picked the third letter:  'SMequipmentID' / 'SMEquipmentID'

```
public abstract class SMequipmentID : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
public virtual int? SMEquipmentID { get; set; }
```

So for this field only (and not all the other ones) you should use the lowercase third letter 'SMequipmentID' in the BQL query.

If you have no access to source code, you can still open the ServiceDispatch.DLL with visual studio or other utilities like ILSpy to search and inspect the type names. Since ServiceDispatch wasn't originally a part of the core Acumatica product it does have a few other naming convention differences:
[image]

Comment: If the field name in the database, which weirdly this happened, it starts with a capital letter. So I'm guessing that we have to change the name in the SQL table to not be uppercase.

Comment: By convention all DB column names created by Acumatica start with an uppercase letter except some audit/utility fields like "tstamp".

Comment: Have you been able to fix the compilation errors and resume your work?

Comment: No because when I change the code to match yours above, I get this: \App_RuntimeCode\ServiceOrderEntry.cs(54): error CS0426: The type name 'sMEquipmentID' does not exist in the type 'FieldService.ServiceDispatch.FSEquipment'
\App_RuntimeCode\ServiceOrderEntry.cs(54): error CS0426: The type name 'sMEquipmentID' does not exist in the type 'FieldService.ServiceDispatch.FSSODetService'

Comment: You found a bug in the naming convention for the FieldService product. Instead of making the first letter upper/lower case like that: 'sMEquipmentID' / 'SMEquipmentID' they picked the third letter:  'SMequipmentID' / 'SMEquipmentID'

Comment: I updated my answer with more detail, please tell me if you're still stuck on this after trying my suggestion.

Comment: It does work but in a weird way. The ServiceID is a selector field, when you first select the Model Number it doesn't update the ServiceID but when I go to select any of the ServiceID's I want in the selector grid, if the Model Number is populated then it will pick the ServiceID that is attached to that Model Number. Basically it is not updating once that field is selected. It updates after I select a random Service ID.

Comment: FieldSelecting event is used to provide a field value on page load. Perhaps what you want is to set CommitChanges on Model Number, add a FieldUpdated event on Model Number and in that event handler change the value of ServiceID. I would suggest asking a new StackOverflow question with desired behavior, current behavior and the full code that you have right now.