# Add Selector Fields In Grid

Tags: grid, customization, acumatica

I am trying to add Selector Fields into a grid. These selectors are not bound to any data on the grid as it's just for data entry so there is no filtering. I am wanting to add the Item Class and Price Class on the Shipping Terms grid.

This is my code:

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Objects;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

namespace PX.Objects.CS
{
  public class ShipTermsDetailExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CS.ShipTermsDetail>
  {
    #region priceCode
  public abstract class priceCode : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Price Code")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<ARPriceClass.PriceClassID>),
    typeof(ARPriceClass.Description),
    SubstituteKey = typeof(ARPriceClass.Description),
    ValidateValue = false)]
    public virtual string UsrPriceCode { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region itemClass
      public abstract class itemClass : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Item Class")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<INItemClass.ItemClassID>),
    typeof(INItemClass.ItemClassCD),
    SubstituteKey = typeof(INItemClass.ItemClassCD),
    ValidateValue = false)]
    public virtual string UsrItemClass { get; set; }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

However I am getting these errors:

```
Building directory '\WebSiteValidationDomain\App_RuntimeCode\'.
\App_RuntimeCode\ShipTermsDetail.cs(20): error CS0118: 'PX.Objects.AR.ARPriceClass.PriceClassID' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'
\App_RuntimeCode\ShipTermsDetail.cs(21): error CS0118: 'PX.Objects.AR.ARPriceClass.Description' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'
\App_RuntimeCode\ShipTermsDetail.cs(22): error CS0118: 'PX.Objects.AR.ARPriceClass.Description' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'
\App_RuntimeCode\ShipTermsDetail.cs(33): error CS0118: 'PX.Objects.IN.INItemClass.ItemClassID' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'
\App_RuntimeCode\ShipTermsDetail.cs(34): error CS0118: 'PX.Objects.IN.INItemClass.ItemClassCD' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'
\App_RuntimeCode\ShipTermsDetail.cs(35): error CS0118: 'PX.Objects.IN.INItemClass.ItemClassCD' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'
\App_RuntimeCode\ShipTermsDetail.cs(20): error CS0118: 'PX.Objects.AR.ARPriceClass.PriceClassID' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'
```

Since these two fields are not bound by what is selected in the first couple of columns, I didn't think a .this or base would be needed but I could be wrong?

Comment: The error you're having are similar to the one linked below. In this case you need to use lowercase letter for your field name because you refer to the field type (column) instead of the field value. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48754170/populate-field-in-grid-with-selection-of-another-field/48754383#48754383

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to watch the naming convention in Acumatica customizations. I just had to change the fields to lowercase for the first letter.

Here is the fixed code:

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Objects;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

namespace PX.Objects.CS
{
  public class ShipTermsDetailExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CS.ShipTermsDetail>
  {
    #region priceCode
  public abstract class priceCode : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Price Code")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<ARPriceClass.priceClassID>),
    typeof(ARPriceClass.description),
    SubstituteKey = typeof(ARPriceClass.description),
    ValidateValue = false)]
    public virtual string UsrPriceCode { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region itemClass
      public abstract class itemClass : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Item Class")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<INItemClass.itemClassID>),
    typeof(INItemClass.itemClassCD),
    SubstituteKey = typeof(INItemClass.itemClassCD),
    ValidateValue = false)]
    public virtual string UsrItemClass { get; set; }
    #endregion
  }
}
```